# Print beginning and ending with a comma in Python?

Tags: python, eclipse, format

```
#!/usr/bin/python

for line in open("blah.txt"):
if "$" in line:
    print (","line",")
```

Why doesn't this work? How can i get a comma at the beginning and end of the line?

Comment: Is the indentation problem in your code or did it occur in typing it here?

Comment: indentation is ok it occurred here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open("blah.txt");       # open file
for line in f:              # iterate over lines in file
  line = line.strip()       # strip leading and trailing white space
  print ("," + line + ",")  # print line between commas
f.close() # close file      # close file when done
```

Comment: Thank you . So you stripped the whitespace and closed the connection.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what you want. Maybe:

```
print ',%s,' % line
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
for line in open("blah.txt"):
    if "$" in line:
        print(",{},".format(line.strip()))
```